# Show decimal type in listbox VB2008

Tags: vb.net, listbox, format-string

I have problem in my project with VB 2008.
I have 5 textbox that only contains numeric. From all of inputted value will be shown in Listbox and sort by ascending. 
I use this code below

```
Private Sub InptBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles InptBtn.Click
    Dim List As New List(Of Double)
    Dim chkList As New Integer
    Dim getData() As String = {Inpt1.Text, Inpt2.Text, Inpt3.Text, Inpt4.Text, Inpt5.Text, Inpt6.Text}

    ' empty check
    For idx As Integer = 0 To getData.Length - 1
        chkList += getData(idx).Trim.Length
    Next

    If chkList = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("EMPTY！", "WARNING!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        Return
    End If

    ' numeric check
    Dim d1 As Double = 0

    For idx As Integer = 0 To getData.Length - 1
        If Double.TryParse(getData(idx), d1) Then
            List.Add(d1)
        End If
    Next

    If List.Count = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill with number！", "WARNING!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        Return
    End If

    List.Sort()
    ListBox.DataSource = List

End Sub
```

It's work! But I have 1 problem.
If I try to input

> 0.0000000000001 or 0.00000000000000000002

It's shown like

> 1E-13 or 2E-20

I tried to use `ToString` method and change List type by `String` after sorting like code below, but it doesn't work.

```
For idx As Integer = 0 To getData.Length - 1
        If Double.TryParse(getData(idx), d1) Then
            List.Add(d1.ToString())
        End If
    Next
```

Could I show all inputted value as I inputted with `Decimal` type? Or there's some way to shown it with other type?
Shown like below in Listbox:

> 0.0000000000001 or 0.00000000000000000002

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
For idx As Integer = 0 To getData.Length - 1
    If Double.TryParse(getData(idx), d1) Then
        List.Add(FormatNumber(d1.ToString, 20))
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't work. If I input `0.00001`, it will show `0.0000100000000000000`.